# Unable to override UICollectionView's willDisplayCell forItemAt method despite implementing UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some reason, am unable to `override willDisplayCell forItemAt` despite conforming to protocol `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Trying to implement a custom `UICollectionFlowLayout`. Need to be able to lazy load via api, by using this delegate method.

[image: unable to override willDisplayCell forItemAt]

I took raywenderlich's final code - https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest for Pinterest layout, and on adding

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("fetch")
}
```

method, fetch was printed every time CV was scrolled.

1. No error shown.
2. If I remove override keyword, then an error is shown - "Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword"

For the working copy, there is override keyword.

PS> This question is now solved, turns out RW was using UICollectionViewController while I used CollectionView on normal ViewController. Hence they had to use override while I didn't need to!

Comment: remove the `override` keyword because it's a delegate method.

Comment: Please check the post again.

Comment: I think you have written the method two times, can you pls share the complete code/

Comment: Hi Sohil, I have not written the method two times. 
I got the function to work anyway, just had to remove the override keyword. However had got confused because in the RW app I tried to edit, autocomplete added 'override' keyword and forced me to keep it. Code also built and ran successfully.
However in mine, I was unable to run the code at all with the override keyword. Will add the code up on git sometime later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` is a protocol func. So you do not have to override. Remove override.

Comment: I took raywenderlich's final code - https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest for Pinterest layout, and on adding override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      print("fetch")
  }
method, fetch was printed every time CV was scrolled. 
1. No error shown. 
2. If I remove override keyword, then an error is shown - "Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword"

For the working copy, there is override keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> **First thing, you don't need to `override` here**

Your class is just `ViewController`, a subclass of `UIViewController` unlike the reference you're giving `PhotoStreamViewController` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`

> **Make sure you're not confirming redundant delegate `UICollectionViewDelegate`, that is in the controller definition and
>   again while extending(screenshot you pasted)**

I have tested the sample from the link you have given, and it's working perfectly.

Needless to say again, conform delegates once:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, PinterestLayoutDelegate {
          //all the required delegate methods
}
```